# error javac: invalid flag: -J-Xmx1028m in sbt

Tags: sbt, javac

I have OutOfMemoryError when I compile my project using sbt. So I need to enlarge the java compiler heap space. I use java 6. And I have set `JAVA_HOME` to java 6 in my bash env.

I tried to add this line to build.sbt

```
javacOptions ++= Seq(<other arguments>,"-J-Xmx1028m")
```

When I compile, I have error like this:

```
[error] javac: invalid flag: -J-Xmx1028m
[error] Usage: javac <options> <source files>
[error] use -help for a list of possible options
```

The funny thing is: this error disappears when I specify the `javaHome` in build.sbt, which I have already done it in my bash env:

```
javaHome := Some(file("path to java 6"))
```

Does it mean that I have to specify `JAVA_HOME` twice? once in bash env, once in build.sbt? I don't want to specify a absolute path in build.sbt, which makes it may not work properly on other computers.

Comment: Shouldn't the setting be `"-Xmx1028m"` (without the `J-`)

Comment: @EECOLOR option "-Xmx1028m" is used with `java` command. `javac` uses "-J" to pass options to jvm. see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html